# Sci-fi movie where some humans (possibly on another planet) stumble upon a huge lost ship with technology better than anything they had

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

I've spent about 3 hours googling every combination of what I can think of and I'm hoping it will jog someone's memory here.

As a child I remember watching a movie on TV (it was older at the time) probably somewhere between 1994 and 1997, but I never got to see the whole thing. This is what I remember about the story.

The characters were human, I'm not sure they were on Earth, but a similar planet. It was set in the future, but the premise was they discovered or stumbled onto a huge lost ship with technology that was better than what they had. It was definitely a "b" movie and seemed kind of similar in story to the "Andromeda" TV Series with Kevin Sorbo.

I can't find anything that seems to be similar and I read about 30 movie summaries on IMDB and Wikipedia. I don't remember any of the actors and I was about 10 at the time, so this is all I can remember. I was hoping to find it and share with my wife.

Edit: Adding more information as requested to the best of my ability. The people who found the ship were not prisoners, but my recollection is that they were normal(ish) people kind of grinding out a meager existence (kind of post apocolyptic). It definitely was not Sphere. I've seen that one all the way through several times, including once recently.

This story struck me as almost like a b movie version of the Andromeda TV series (which didn't exist yet). Thank you to everyone posting ideas.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Just to avoid any possible confusion, did you _watch_ this movie between 1994 and 1997, or is that when you think it was made?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive about the human characters? Were they scientists? Military? Regular folk? A combination thereof? And did they have a city on this planet? A town? A basecamp? A ship of their own?

Comment: Lost in Space fits some of these tropes

Comment: This sounds superficially like Sphere. Starting Dustin Hoffman. Released in the late 1990s so might just fit your timescale... Read about it on tv tropes here... https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Sphere

Comment: Sounds like a repeat of Blake's 7... but I do not know if it actually WAS repeated in the 1990s.

Comment: @AJM there *was* a supercut of Blakes7 which was released on VHS in the 1980s and on TV in the 1990s a few times, which consisted of several episodes from the first three seasons joined as a tv movie or mini series (of two VHS tapes).  Until the 2000s, this was the only Blakes7 I had watched...

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like it might have been [Blake's 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blake%27s_7). This was a British TV series from around 1980. In the first few episodes, a spaceship carrying criminals on its way to a prison planet finds a gigantic, abandoned alien warship. The prison ship's captain sends some prisoners to check it out (because they're expendable), but the prisoners turn the tables on him and take control of the alien ship, which they name *Liberator*.

Comment: Sending *prisoners* to examine an abandoned **warship**... not too bright.  No wonder that guy captained a prison ship!!!

Comment: @RonJohn several of the ships crew were sent first, only to either die or go insane.  Which was why the prisoners were sent.